# Wolfram-Cloud/Mathematica, effective working with recursive functions

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I am working with Чебышёв-polynomials at the moment, recursive defined polynomials. For the very likely case you never saw them before:

```
f[0,x_]  := 1;
f[1,x_]  := x;
f[n_,x_] := 2 * x * f[n-1, x] - f[n-2, x];
Plot[{f[9, x],f[3, x]},{x, -1, 1}]
```

And I found myself asking, since I usually work with python, if there is a way to build an array of functions in wolfram-cloud, to ease the process.

Thus I have to calculate every `f[n]` only once, allowing me to improve the run-time quite a bit and also allowing me to extend the range of n.

Comment: The typical way to solve this problem in Mathematica is memoization.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using the inbuilt function `ChebyshevT` ?  My naive expectation is that using this will improve run-time quite a bit, with very little effort on your part.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It's fair to ask, so I wanted to a) learn something about the syntax and b) actually wanted to play around with the polynomial myself, so I get a better grasp of it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Does this also hold for functions or does this only hold for specific values. Also is there a way to pre-run some part of it, so it won't time out. So can I break it down in multiple calculations?

Comment: @Szabolcs I have to falsify myself. It actually doesn't. I tried to make a working sample and tried to calculate the run-time without any output or simplifying the polynomial.
So I suppressed the output of the polynomial `f[27,x]` and tried to calculate it once and access it afterwards without outputing it. Both times I checked the time before minus the time after the calculation. And each time it took 3.1 seconds.
Either implying that looking it up takes ages and that it was pre-calculated (in a fresh book) or that it actually calculated it both times.

Comment: Memoization is trickier because we don't want to remember `x` here, only the form of the polynomial. I wrote an answer.

Comment: Something else you can learn about Mathematica and recursive functions:  RSolve[{f[0,x]==1, f[1,x]==x, f[n,x]==2 x f[n-1,x]-f[n-2,x]}, f[n,x], {n,x}] instantly discovers that f[n, x] == ((x-Sqrt[-1+x^2])^n+(x+Sqrt[-1+x^2])^n)/2. That won't always work, but sometimes it is useful.

Comment: @Bill That is kind of neat, I guess, but I wasn't interested in solving nor in simplifying the recursion. And Mathematica should also be able to identify its already built-in function ChebyshevT[n,x].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

In this case memoization is trickier than usual because we work with functions, not function values.

```
Clear[cheb]
cheb[0] = 1 &;
cheb[1] = # &;
cheb[n_] := cheb[n] = Evaluate@Expand[2 # cheb[n - 1][#] - cheb[n - 2][#]] &
```

The `Evaluate` makes sure that the insides of the `Function` get evaluated even before supplying and argument.

Comment: Might I ask why you are using `&;` instead of `;`

Comment: And where is actually `#` defined. Just tried it, and it spit some `#` Formula as output.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Look up `Function` and see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html  You can enter `#` or `&` into the documentation search box and you will be taken to the relevant page. When learning Mathematica, always check the documentation first (before googling, etc.). It is better than that of most other systems.

Comment: Still the code you wrote isn't working, at least in the cloud version.
And I have somewhat a hard time figuring out how I can make it work.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham It is working perfectly fine. If you have trouble with it, show what you did, what you got as a result and what you expected. Remember that `cheb[10]` is a function, not a number.

Comment: I repeated exactly what I did before and it just worked fine.
Maybe I just need some sleep ;)
Thanks for taking the time and a good evening

Comment: PS: The process time is down to a few ms.
40+ isn't a problem, like it was before.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Beware of caching too many results though. In this case it won't be a problem as you probably don't need `cheb[10000]`.  But if there  is more than one argument, memoization is more difficult and it can go wrong. You can use `?cheb` to check what is being cached, and `Clear[cheb]` to clear all definitions.  Something else: consider asking on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ next time.